# How to scroll away Activity's toolbar by scrolling its Navigation Component fragment

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, android-architecture-navigation

Help me please.
I have an Activity with Toolbar and fragment container (a `<fragment>`, because I use `Navigation Component` in app).
**Goal**: Scroll down Activity’s toolbar upon fragment’s content scroll.   E. i. when fragment is scrolled far down, only the content of fragment is visible.
The standard solution of setting `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` for `toolbar` and         `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` for `fragment` **does not work**.
Currently when I scroll down fragment, Activity's toolbar stays at place.
XML of Activity:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_carrier_root"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/carrier_root_nav_graph" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NestedScrollView and set:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

this NSV could be the fragment parent or be inside a fragment inside your nav graph